# syncing slideshow with music

Tags: framerate, sync, music

So im currently creating a music oriented slideshow with a bundle of images that needs to be changed each beat of the music. Problem is, the music is 129 bpm which results in 2.15 beats per second. Having the image change each beat would take me approximately 27.9069767442 frames for each image to show up before changing to another one in a 60 fps sequence. knowing the capabilities of my software, i can only go 27 or 28 frames per image which resulted the slide show being not precise to the beat, it slows down in certain parts of the music when im using 28 frames per image and it speeds up when im using 27 frames per second.

Is there any **easy** and **time saving** way to sync up my images before i resort to brute force (adjusting the frames manually)? Perhaps is there a way to change the frame rate im working on to a desired number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some ideas.

**1. Do not sync everything.**

Define what out of sync is acceptable to you. Let's say 1/10 sec. (I would be way less "picky" and go for let's say 1/5)

Then calculate how many images you need to accumulate that out of sync, and only adjust that. This will be now adjusting only let's say one of every 10 clips.

**2. Choose a "multiple" framerate**

To reduce even more the out of sync, and retime later. Let's say you choose a framerate of 10x faster, then the out of framing could be rounded a bit more accurately. 279 frames. Then retime.